# When I change renderers from eevee to cycles, the render view looks grey

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I´m new to render.

I did all of the 3d model and materials with eevee, and when I change it to cycles I have two problems, the objects look grey in the render view, and, in the render image itsel.

While the shading and all looks great, there is missing information from the materials.

I think that it might have something to do with the bump and the normals, but I couldn´t tell.

Example on the left the eevee renderer and on the right the cycles renderer, The pictures are low quality due to this web limits, but if you compare them I think it´s quite noticeable the lack of texture.

[image: Example on the left the eevee renderer and on the right the cycles renderer, The pictures are low quality due to this web limits, but if you compare them I think it´s quite noticeable the lack of texture.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer was quite simple, as @kemplerart mentioned it! Kindly properly rephrase your question. Lack of textures? After checking your screenshots in detail, it looks more like a blank viewport and it is clearly written: "rendering paused". The phrasing of your question confuses readers, it sounds more like a 'detail' comparison between Eevee and cycles rather than a blank viewport. They're not missing textures, the whole object is missing since you paused it between processing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to see the screenshots separated - to see better.
From what I've found, looks like you had pause the render, resume it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've phrased your question in a very confusing way, making it difficult for us to figure out what you may want, here's an addition to @kemplerart's answer:

Cycles is a ray-traced render engine. Eevee on the other hand is real-time but does not use ray tracing. Through experience, I've discovered that Eevee takes more influence on your world shading or background and lights than cycles. Cycles, however, is influenced by the lighting more like a real-life situation, making your cycles render look more saturated (It's also related to the light bounces in cycles). See more on cycles in the blender documentation on https://blender.org, I would've explained in more detail but there are a lot of answers here that do that.